# How to pre default a select field with jQuery on page load

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have had a developer create some code below in my wordpress footer.php file to predefault a set of fields based on the user's profile.

The text fields seem to default fine however the select option (gender) does not default and the user has to select this option, even though the value is stored against their profile.

Is there a way to update this code to have the gender default? I think it is something to do with using .val()??

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();


/**
 * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
 *     return;
 */
$username = $current_user->user_login;
$email = $current_user->user_email;
$firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
$lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;
$displayname = $current_user->display_name;
//$user_id = $current_user->phone;




if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$email = $current_user->user_email;
$name  = $current_user->user_firstname.' '.$current_user->user_lastname;
$golflink = $current_user->dbem_golf_link;
$home_club = $current_user->dbem_home_club;
$handicap = $current_user->dbem_handicap;
$gender = $current_user->dbem_gender;
}
    ?>


jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery('#attendee_name').val("<?php echo $firstname.' '.$lastname; ?>");
jQuery('#golflink').val("<?php echo $golflink; ?>");
jQuery('#home_club').val("<?php echo $home_club; ?>");
jQuery('#handicap').val("<?php echo $handicap; ?>");
jQuery('#gender').val("<?php echo $gender; ?>");
```

Any advice would be great.

From other reading, can I just change:
    jQuery('#gender').val("");
to 
    jQuery('select#gender').val("");

I tried the above but no changes.

The select I created in wordpress was 'Male' and 'Female'

Thanks

Comment: what is the value of `$gender;`

Answer (score 2):

To give value for a `select` in jquery, the value you are passing should be same as the value of the select box.

**Example 1:**

```
$gender = "male" or "female";//any value you want

<select name="gender" id="gender">
     <option value="male">Male</option>
                    ^  this should be same as your $gender
     <option value="female">Female</option>
                    ^  this should be same as your $gender
</select>
```

Then

```
jQuery('#gender').val("<?php echo $gender; ?>");
```

`$gender` has value as `male`, so male will be selected.

**Example 2:**

```
$gender = "male" or "female";//any value you want

<select name="gender" id="gender">
     <option value="0">Male</option>
                    ^  this should be same as your $gender
     <option value="1">Female</option>
                    ^  this should be same as your $gender
</select>
```

Then

```
jQuery('#gender').val("<?php echo $gender; ?>");
```

`$gender` has value as `0 or 1`, But select box value is `male` and `female`. So even though you have passed the value, it will not work.

Comment: Ok thanks we have the underlining field in as a select in the wordpress. called dbem_gender with options of 'Male' and 'Female'.  However we have noticed that our buddypress profile refers to a input field of text. Would this impact. `<label for="dbem_gender"><?php _e('Gender','buddypress');?></label>
   <input type="text" name="dbem_gender" id="dbem_gender" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user_id,'dbem_gender',true); ?>" class="settings-input" <?php bp_form_field_attributes( 'gender' ); ?> >`